# How to read data from a different file without using YAML or JSON

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm experimenting with a Ruby script that will add data to a Neo4j database using REST API. ([Here's the tutorial with all the code if interested.](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-neo4j-graph-database-using-rest-api/))

The script works if I include the hash data structure in the initialize method but I would like to move the data into a different file so I can make changes to it separately using a different script.

I'm relatively new to Ruby. If I copy the following data structure into a separate file, is there a simple way to read it from my existing script when I call @data? I've heard one could do something with YAML or JSON (not familiar with how either work). What's the easiest way to read a file and how could I go about coding that?

```
#I want to copy this data into a different file and read it with my script when I call @data.
{
  nodes:[
        {:label=>"Person", :title=>"title_here", :name=>"name_here"}
        ]
}
```

And here is part of my code, it should be enough for the purposes of this question.

```
class RGraph

  def initialize    

    @url = 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher'

    #If I put this hash structure into a different file, how do I make @data read that file?
    @data = {
            nodes:[
                {:label=>"Person", :title=>"title_here", :name=>"name_here"}
            ]
            } 


  end

  #more code here... not relevant to question

  def create_nodes
    # Scan file, find each node and create it in Neo4j
    @data.each do |key,value|
        if key == :nodes
            @data[key].each do |node| # Cycle through each node
                next unless node.has_key?(:label) # Make sure this node has a label
                #WE have sufficient data to create a node
                label = node[:label]
                attr = Hash.new
                node.each do |k,v| # Hunt for additional attributes
                    next if k == :label # Don't create an attribute for "label"
                    attr[k] = v
                end
                create_node(label,attr)
             end
          end
      end
  end

rGraph = RGraph.new

rGraph.create_nodes

end
```

Comment: When you write data to a file, that file has to have a certain format. You can invent your own, in which case no-one (including you 6 months later) will know what you wrote; or you can use one of the standard ones, JSON, YAML, XML (all human-readable) or Marshall (not human-readable). Furthermore, it is trivially easy to read/write one of those formats in Ruby, so there is really no reason not to use them unless you are deliberately trying to make things difficult. Do you have any better reason for not wanting to use a standard format beyone "not familiar how either work"?

Comment: @Amadan. Thanks. Makes sense. I'm not against using either of those or learning how they work. But right now I'm trying to work with the data structure that was given with this script because it makes it much easier to import into Neo4j because of how the Neo4j data structure works.

Comment: Choosing a standard serialisation format would not change your structure.

Comment: Just read it in as YAML (or JSON, or whatever) and manipulate directly as data. Do you have any reason why you would want to read it as lines? What kind of manipulation you want to do in that other script?

Comment: @Amadan Good to know, thanks. And no, I just want to read the entire data block and iterate through it later on.

Comment: Ruby tip to make your code a bit more expressive: `@data.select {|key, _| key == :nodes }.values.flatten.select {|node| node.has_key?(:label) }.each {|node| }`

Comment: Also you might want to check out the `neo4j` / `neo4j-core` gems.  I'm one of the maintainers and I'm happy to help if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that OP said in comments "I'm not against using either of those", let's do it in YAML (which preserves the Ruby object structure best). Save it:

```
@data = {
        nodes:[
            {:label=>"Person", :title=>"title_here", :name=>"name_here"}
        ]
    } 
require 'yaml'
File.write('config.yaml', YAML.dump(@data))
```

This will create `config.yaml`:

```
---
:nodes:
- :label: Person
  :title: title_here
  :name: name_here
```

If you read it in, you get exactly what you saved:

```
require 'yaml'
@data = YAML.load(File.read('config.yaml'))
puts @data.inspect
# => {:nodes=>[{:label=>"Person", :title=>"title_here", :name=>"name_here"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and explanation. I had looked at some other YAML examples earlier but couldn't apply it to this case, seeing your code here really helps.